# why my ip address change automatically in ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have configured my server with static ip address but when happens a certain time change the ip address and I have to restart the network to put the original ip address.

This is my configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.1.218
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.100
nameserver 192.168.1.210
```

thank's